# TYPO3 Cannot Access to Installtool after upgrade from 9 to 10

Tags: typo3, upgrade, typo3-10.x

i've updated from Version 9.5 to 10.4 and after that i cant acces the Installtool anymore.

It stucks at "Checking session and executing silent configuration update"...

All i want is to repair the Database! Is there any other way to do this?

The Console log shows me "GET [https://mywebsite.net/typo3/install.php?install[controller]=layout&install[action]=executeSilentConfigurationUpdate](https://mywebsite.net/typo3/install.php?install%5Bcontroller%5D=layout&install%5Baction%5D=executeSilentConfigurationUpdate) 200 OK" over and over again (canceled at 4000 trys..)

Any idea?

Comment: Maybe, it's an issue with referrers: `['SYS']['features']['security.backend.enforceReferrer'] = false`. For details: https://typo3.org/security/advisory/typo3-core-sa-2020-006

Comment: Thanks! You made my day :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
['SYS']['features']['security.backend.enforceReferrer'] = false
```

Comment: This is a quick fix but removes a security layer, thus making the system vulnerable to one kind of attack.

Answer (score 0):

The TYPO3 backend wants proper referers since [TYPO3-CORE-SA-2020-006: Same-Origin Request Forgery to Backend User Interface](https://typo3.org/security/advisory/typo3-core-sa-2020-006), and your TYPO3 backend is behind a reverse proxy.

You have to configure the reverse proxy settings, see [an explanation](https://www.wacon.de/en/typo3-know-how/missing-referrer-for-main.html) and [the documentation](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/11.5/en-us/Configuration/Typo3ConfVars/SYS.html#reverseproxyip).

Options I had to set:

- reverseProxyHeaderMultiValue
- reverseProxyIP
- reverseProxySSL